# When to create a method inside anonymous class

Tags: java, android, class, onclicklistener, protected

In the code below, I created the button listener and when I tried to create the method `on()` eclipse suggested to create it as part of the `OnClickListener` or as part of the mainClass.

What is the difference beteen creating the method `on()` in both cases, and why it should be `protected`?

**code**:

```
private OnClickListener btnListenerOn = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        on();
    }
};
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    Log.w(TAG, "@onStart.");
}

protected void on() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Encapsulation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4772966/2032064) is the concept that should give you a lead on where to place the method. Encapsulation helps you hide your implementation details to the most limited scope so that, e.g., you can prevent [ripple effect](http://versasolution.blogspot.cz/2010/08/what-is-encapsulation-and-ripple.html) when you need to change the implementation.

In your case, since you probably don't need to call the `on()` method from any other place then your `OnClickListener`, this is the right place to put it.

In that case the `on()` method should be private because you will never extend the anonymous `OnClickListener` class. If your listener was not anonymous, you may  want to declare the method protected so that you can override the implementation in subclasses